# Running Migrations in Startup.cs not working with tests using WebApplicationFactory<Startup>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, testing, entity-framework-core, integration-testing

I have written some integration tests for my ASP .NET Core application using XUnit and the `WebApplicationFactory<Startup>` class. After spending a long time figuring out why I get a lot of `SqlServerExceptions` whenever they run for the first time (i.e. when the database does not exist yet), I figured out the issue is that running `context.Database.Migrate()` in my `Startup.cs` does not behave well with the factory. I think perhaps this is because of tests running in parallel and a race condition resulting in two factories thinking there is no database yet and attempting to run the same migrations.

I get errors like the following:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Database 'MyApplicationDB' already exists. Choose a different database name.
...
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.
...
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : There is already an object named '__EFMigrationsHistory' in the database.
```

etc.

I've "solved" the issue by removing the migration step at startup and instead running the migrations with the `dotnet` cli and running `dotnet test`.

My question: Is there a way to configure `WebApplicationFactory`s to play nicely with each other when there is a migration step in the `Startup` class? Or are migrations at startup altogether a bad idea?

Comment: Yes... don't run the tests in parallel.

Comment: What version of .net core are you using, you can read this article, there are good examples and explanations, which may help you: https://andrewlock.net/converting-integration-tests-to- net-core-3/

Comment: @Chaodeng something went wrong with your hyperlink. https://andrewlock.net/converting-integration-tests-to-net-core-3/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use an `InMemoryDatabase`?
In that case you can do something like this within a derived `WebApplicationFactory`:

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(o =>
        {
            // Make sure that every test has its own database to prevent concurrency issues in tests.
            var inMemoryDbName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            o.UseInMemoryDatabase(inMemoryDbName);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try when I get a chance.